# Recorded sound gets noisy/distorted when datatype is 32 bit float

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, pyaudio, python-sounddevice

I recorded sound from microphone on my computer by python with pyaudio. It works fine when sound is recorded in 16 bit integer as its data type. However, it does not work when it is recorded in 32 bit float as its datatype.

Please take a look at the following code. If the FORMAT is set to pyaudio.paInt16 it works as I wanted. However it does not work when it is set to be pyaudio.paFloat32 as follows;

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paFloat32
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 3
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "path/to/output_file.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
frames = []

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,channels=CHANNELS,rate=RATE,input=True,frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

Thank you so much for your advice and help in advance!

Update;

I have tested sounddevice and code is following;

```
import sounddevice as sd
import wave

CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "path/to/output.wav"

myrecording = sd.rec(int(RECORD_SECONDS * RATE), samplerate=RATE,
                     channels=CHANNELS, blocking=True, dtype='int16')
print(myrecording, 'myrecording')

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(2)
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(myrecording)
wf.close()
```

The result was the same as pyaudio. It worked when int16 but it generated noise and sound distortion when 32 bit float as dtype.

Comment: I guess the problem is not the recording but the conversion of the recorded data to the WAV file. What about using the [soundfile](https://pypi.org/project/SoundFile/) module, which does the conversion for you? You could try something like `import soundfile as sf; sf.write(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, myrecording, RATE)`.

Comment: @Matthias Yes, you are right. I recorded in 32 bit float and wrote it in 16 bit int then it sound as I wanted in pyaudio. and It was successful to write it in 32 bit float by using soundfile! Thanks a lot!